# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr' on Writing a Pandas Data Frame to S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

Got `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'` while writing a pandas data frame to S3.

```
import awswrangler as wr
window = '0112'
wr.s3.to_csv(
    df=mergeDf,
    path="s3://MYBUCKET/wrangled/" + "WiderData_2" +window+ ".csv"
)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-30cb4c51bd25> in <module>
      7 # Use 'w' for py3, 'wb' for py2
      8 with s3.open('........','w') as f:
----> 9     mergeDf.to_csv(f)
.....
~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272         """
   5273         Return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame.
-> 5274 
   5275         .. warning::
   5276 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'
```

Also Tried

```
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
# Use 'w' for py3, 'wb' for py2
with s3.open('MYBUCEKT/wrangled/WiderData_1011.csv','w') as f:
    mergeDf.to_csv(f)
```

Same Error `'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr' '`

Answer (score 0):

just use boto3 as so

```
    import boto3
    import io
    import pandas as pd
    bucket='yourbucket'
    key='path/to/file.csv'
    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    response = boto3.client('s3').put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Comment: Still The Same Error. data = {'A':[1, 2, 3],  
            'B':[4, 5, 6],  
            'C':[7, 8, 9] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd
bucket='vz-bhr-ml-sha-inputdata'
key='wrangled/test.csv'
csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
response = boto3.client('s3').put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

 df.to_csv(csv_buffer) -> 5274 
   5275         .. warning::
   5276 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr

Comment: Post your df. Seems to be more of df issue than s3 issue. or a pandas issue  Have you searched SO for that error?

Comment: The Error is the Same.. I observed another thing, I opened a new NoteBook Instance, and tried it worked. But once I issue [ !pip install awswrangler ] the even the @Jonathan Leon's Suggestion fails. But the old code worked a couple of months before. Seems like awswrangler package has some update without basic QA,QC that is messing up.